# Will the sum of subsets always remain a subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I,\:J_{\beta }$ be ideals, R is the ring those ideals are from

If we have that:

$$\forall _{\beta }\:\:r\in R\::\:r\:\cdot \:J_{\beta }\:\subset \:I$$

Does this mean that

$$\sum _{\beta }\left(\:r\:\cdot \:\:J_{\beta \:}\right)\:\subset \:I$$

too?

Comment: for any $r\in R$, by definition of an ideal, $rJ_\beta\subseteq J_\beta$ for each $\beta$. so you may assume that $r=1$, ie that $rJ_\beta=J_\beta$. and indeed, if $J_\beta\subseteq I$ for every $\beta$, then $\sum_{\beta}J_\beta\subseteq I$. to see this, first do you know the definition of a sum of ideals? your question title seems to ask about arbitrary subsets, but there is no standard definition for a sum of arbitrary subsets, so you need to use the definition of a sum of ideals somewhere.

Comment: Yes I know the definition but how can we be sure that there isn't an element in our sum of ideals which is not included in I? I mean every element in a sum of ideals is a sum of their elements, but I don't see what to do next

Comment: suppose $x$ is an arbitrary element of $\sum_{\beta} J_\beta$. then by definition there are some $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ and some elements $y_i\in J_{\beta_i}$ such that $x=y_1+\dots+y_n$. now, for each $i\leqslant n$, we know $J_{\beta_i}\subseteq I$. hence $y_i\in I$ for each $i\leqslant n$. what can we conclude about $x$?

Comment: Because all those y_i are elements from our ideal I, the sum of those y_i (also known as x) will belong to I, too, thus the sum of our J_beta will also belong to I. But this can only be true if I is an ideal, what if it isn't an ideal?

Comment: oh! if $I$ is not an ideal then the result certainly does not hold. for instance, let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, let $J_1=(x)$, let $J_2=(y)$, and let $I=J_1\cup J_2$. then, for example, $x+y\in J_1+J_2$, but $x+y\notin I$. however, if $I$ is an ideal, what you have written is absolutely right :)